# Github syncing fails

Tags: git, github

All described refers to Github for windows.

I tried to sync my commit. I got Fail sync message. My commit was shown as unsynced commit. And there was no sync button on the top right. So I pressed the master button.

[image: Screenshot]

There was something like a merge. I don't exactly remember. It seems I changed branches (don't know) and then pushed commit and sync. Sync failed there was a message if direct on sync button "1 commit by ahead, behind by 1 commit.

Then my last unsynced commit disappeared and previous commit appeared as unsynced. Finally I opened the C# project from Explorer and it's in the stage of previous commit. How to retrieve my last changes?

Answer (score 0):

What I get from your post, I guess it might help you. The post is ambiguous and from your link, it is not clear on which state you are...so far you can try

Try to do any of the following -

1. `git reset --hard HEAD`.

Or You can go to your 'git history' by

2.`git reflog` or `git log`. [I prefer `git reflog`]

there you can see all your `commit` history.

To get back any of the previous stage 
`git reset --hard <commit>` [you will get your commit reference from `git reflog` command]